# Pyspark Dataframes Resolved attribute(s) error with no matching column names

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe *graphcounts* with a hero Id and connections as below

```
+------+-----------+
|heroId|connections|
+------+-----------+
|   691|          7|
|  1159|         12|
|  3959|        143|
|  1572|         36|
|  2294|         15|
|  1090|          5|
|  3606|        172|
|  3414|          8|
|   296|         18|
|  4821|         17|
|  2162|         42|
|  1436|         10|
|  1512|         12|
```

I have another dataframe *graph_names* with hero id and names as below.

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|                name|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|24-HOUR MAN/EMMANUEL|
|  2|3-D MAN/CHARLES CHAN|
|  3|    4-D MAN/MERCURIO|
|  4|             8-BALL/|
|  5|                   A|
|  6|               A'YIN|
|  7|        ABBOTT, JACK|
|  8|             ABCISSA|
|  9|                ABEL|
| 10|ABOMINATION/EMIL BLO|
| 11|ABOMINATION | MUTANT|
| 12|         ABOMINATRIX|
| 13|             ABRAXAS|
| 14|          ADAM 3,031|
| 15|             ABSALOM|
```

I am attempting to create a map column that can be used to lookup *heroId* in *graphcounts* with the *name* in *graph_names* which throws me below error. I have referred to this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10925 from another thread but my column names are not the same. I don't understand the exception message also to know how I can debug this.

```
>>> mapper = fn.create_map([graph_names.id, graph_names.name])
>>> mapper
Column<b'map(id, name)'>
>>>
>>> graphcounts.printSchema()
root
 |-- heroId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- connections: long (nullable = true)
>>>
>>> graph_names.printSchema()
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
>>>
>>>
>>> graphcounts.withColumn('name', mapper[graphcounts['heroId']]).show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 2096, in withColumn
    return DataFrame(self._jdf.withColumn(colName, col._jc), self.sql_ctx)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 134, in deco
    raise_from(converted)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) id#242,name#243 missing from heroId#189,connections#203L in operator !Project [heroId#189, connections#203L, map(id#242, name#243)[heroId#189] AS name#286].;;
!Project [heroId#189, connections#203L, map(id#242, name#243)[heroId#189] AS name#286]
+- Project [heroId#189, sum(connections)#200L AS connections#203L]
   +- Aggregate [heroId#189], [heroId#189, sum(cast(connections#192 as bigint)) AS sum(connections)#200L]
      +- Project [value#7, heroId#189, (size(split(value#7,  , -1), true) - 1) AS connections#192]
         +- Project [value#7, split(value#7,  , 2)[0] AS heroId#189]
            +- Relation[value#7] text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the error was there are headers for each column of the dataframe. However when I reading with schema and without including header=True, the header column name became one of the column values. The lookup failed as there is no name with that column.